# Missing audio settings

Tags: audio

I recently updated my raspberry pi and I can no longer find the audio device settings.

Below is an image of what I'm looking for

[image]

I'm guessing that they've removed it from the distro and I'll have to manually add it. Does anyone know which package I need to install in order to get it back?

I've already tried installing a few audio packages but haven't had any success.

Thanks

P.S: I'm aware that there are audio settings under raspi-config, unfortunately they're quite limited.

Comment: Is your audio not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That audio setting is for pulseaudio driver. Now Raspbian use ALSA driver and ALSA driver doesn't need this menu.

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install rtkit
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
sudo apt-get install lxplug-volumepulse
```